# How to know if invalid date was entered using Angular-Strap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

I'm using a very simple implementation of the Angular-Strap datepicker directive. On the home page for [Angular-Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers), if something invalid is entered, the input text elements indicates this by outlining with red. I'm not getting that in my implementation:

```
<input type="text" size="10" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.InitiationDate" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" autoclose="true" name="date" bs-datepicker />
```

What is causing the input element on the Angular Strap sample page to go red, but no validation seems to occur on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date picker needs to be part of a `<form>` and then the `ng-class` directive can select an error class.

```
<form name="datepickerForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
  <!-- Basic example -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': datepickerForm.date.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date <small>(as date)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" bs-datepicker>
  </div>
```

For more information:

- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)
- [AngularJS form.FormController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: Is it possible to do that without a form?